# Can a Vue 3 + Typescript project use RxJS v7?

Tags: vue.js, rxjs, vuejs3

Created a Vue3 + typescript project and added the rxjs 7 dependency using vue cli.

When I try `import { Observable } from 'rxjs'`, I get `Could not find a declaration file for module 'rxjs'`

Trying to add `@types/rxjs` or adding a `declare module 'rxjs'` doesn't work.
Adding `rxjs` to the tsconfig types doesn't either.

Comment: `rxjs` has typings available in its distribution at `index.d.ts`, and its `package.json` points to it. There's no need to configure your project to use it. I cannot reproduce the symptom in a Vue CLI scaffolded project. Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: @tony19: New project with only rxjs dependency : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0694847494f9bda41aa4e9eb1abf746a20210719064941/d90041 (zip file).  Still get the error in the vue file when I try to import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RXJS 7 requires TS 4.2+
See the [breaking changes](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/breaking-changes) section.

The version used by Vue 3 generator (at the moment of writing this), is ~4.1.5.
It is using ~ symbol, which won't use a 4.2.X version of TS.

Answer (score 0):

> RXJS 7 requires TS 4.2+ See the breaking changes section.
>
> The version used by Vue 3 generator (at the moment of writing this),
> is ~4.1.5. It is using ~ symbol, which won't use a 4.2.X version of
> TS.

Indeed, my original package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
    ...
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.15",
    ...
    "typescript": "~4.1.5",
     ...
  }
}
```

So I ran:

```
npm install --save-dev typescript@4.6
npm install --save-dev @vue/cli-plugin-typescript@4
npm install --save-dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm install --save-dev @typescript-eslint/parser
```

resulting package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.33.0",
    ...
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^4.5.19",
    ...
    "typescript": "4.6",
    ...
  }
```

This solved the errors in my project.